# automatically upload csv to mysql .net mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, csv

I'm trying to make an information screen that pulls information from multiple .csv files that displays both single values from the .csv files and also a couple of lists. These .csv files are autogenerated and owerwritten in the directory every 30 minutes.

Is there a way to automatically upload these .csv files every 30 min when they are updated, storing them and overwriting the previous information in a small sql database and then pulling the values from the sql database while showing it in the browser? Should I do this some other way?

I am using Visual Basic 2013 Premium and .NET MVC 4.

Comment: is it mysql or sql server? please use proper tags.

Comment: 1) How big are .csv files? 2) Are they all in the same format? I would load them into some kind of cache that expires every 30 minutes after which that cache would be refreshed with new values. I am also not sure what you mean by uploading, since you already have them on file system.